# Progressive loading in ng-repeat for images, angular js

Tags: angularjs, lazy-loading, angularjs-ng-repeat, progressive

How do I implement progressive loading of content as you scroll down the page? Otherwise 1000 images would load at the same time.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I didn't want to use `ngInfiniteScroll` the other guy posted as my mobile app does not use jQuery so there is no point in loading it just for this.

Anyhow, I found a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/U7Bz9/) with pure Javascript that solves this problem.

**HTML**

```
<div id="fixed" when-scrolled="loadMore()">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="i in items"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function Main($scope) {
    $scope.items = [];
    var counter = 0;
    $scope.loadMore = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            $scope.items.push({
                id: counter
            });
            counter += 10;
        }
    };
    $scope.loadMore();
}

angular.module('scroll', []).directive('whenScrolled', function() {
    return function(scope, elm, attr) {
        var raw = elm[0];
        elm.bind('scroll', function() {
            if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight >= raw.scrollHeight) {
                scope.$apply(attr.whenScrolled);
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Source: http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/U7Bz9/

Comment: This solution doesn't deal with page resize (by the user) or div resize, so you could be left with blank space even though there are more items "waiting" to be added.

Comment: This makes use of Angular aswell, just like the infinite scrolling answer EpokK gave.

Answer (score 24):

Use *infinite scrolling* directive. [ngInfiniteScroll](https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/index.html)

[DEMO](http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_basic.html)

---

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='DemoController'>
  <div infinite-scroll='loadMore()' infinite-scroll-distance='2'>
    <img ng-repeat='image in images' ng-src='http://placehold.it/225x250&text={{image}}'>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['infinite-scroll']);
myApp.controller('DemoController', function($scope) {
  $scope.images = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

  $scope.loadMore = function() {
    var last = $scope.images[$scope.images.length - 1];
    for(var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
      $scope.images.push(last + i);
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Is there a non Jquery solution? as this is for a mobile app.

Comment: By default, AngularJS **does not** use jQuery. And zepto is definitely a bad choice (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/3350)