# AngularJS - JSON data not showing in ng-repeat but does in console log

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having difficult time displaying my JSON data from an API call I make, but I can see the response if I console log it.

My app is build up like this

```
angular.module('myApp', ['angularSoundManager', 'infinite-scroll'])
.controller('MovieController', function($scope, $http){

$scope.songs = [];
$scope.data = $scope.songs.slice(0, 20);
$scope.getMoreData = function () {
$scope.data = $scope.songs.slice(0, $scope.data.length + 10);
};
```

Function to fetch data

```
function fetch(){
$http.get("http://www.someAPI.com" + $scope.search + "&perpage=150")
.success(function(response){
 $scope.details = response;
 console.log(response);

 // for loop happens here to loop through the data and push it to the empty array

  for(var i=0; i < response.tracks.length; i++){

    var allTracks = {
    title: response.tracks[i].primary_title,
    };

 };
 $scope.songs.push(allTracks);
}
```

My HTML is

```
<div infinite-scroll='getMoreData()' infinite-scroll-distance='1'>
          <div ng-repeat="song in data">
           {{song.title}}
          </div>
        </div>
```

I can see if I `console.log(response)` I get `Object {ID: 0, tracks: Array[150], total: 257}`

On the other hand I can display my data if I use `ng-repeat="song in songs"` instead. It has something to do with me assigning `$scope.data` to `$scope.songs`

Reason why I want this to work with the slice is to be able to use infinite-scroll because I can expect from 100 to 15.000 results on my page

Comment: Your `getMoreData` function returns always the ten first songs.

Comment: Yes, when I search for tracks, it should display the ten first songs and then when I call the function it should add 10 more to it. Strangely when I limit the results per page down to maybe 30 then it works. It's like it can't handle over 100 results.

Comment: So what are you actually seeing displayed on the page?

Comment: If I limit the results below 100 then I see what I want .. if I try to go over that then it wont show anything inside the ng-repeat div but I can still see it being fetched in the console log and being pushed to the array

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
angular.copy(source,destination);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can limit your ng-repeat by putting limitTo:100

```
<div ng-repeat="s in song" | limitTo:100">
    {{s.title}}
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to do any good, besides I don't want to limit the results. I want all the results to display whether they are only 10 or 15.000

Comment: well, thats right, didn't read this properly :) check this answer [then](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18206656/3033318)